# Most common record in QuerySet Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

Hi how can I select records ordered by the most common record in Django.

My model is:

```
Action|User|Date
-----------------
sport |Mark|00/00/2000
study |Alex|00/00/2001
sport |Paul|00/00/2010
```

Sport is the most common aciton. How can I filter QuerySet to get data ordered this way?

Sport

Study

Comment: Do you want to filter data? Only show `sport`'s rows? Or ordered data? First `sport`'s rows, then others?

Answer (score 2):

As you have not posted your model so here is a rough query to order by most common action first:

```
from django.db.models import Count

qs = MyModel.objects.annotate(c=Count('action')).order_by('-c')
```